# 8 Ball Pool (Miniclip) on Android x86

Tags: android-x86, dell

I'm using Android x86 emulator on a Dell Vostro 3500.
I installed 8 Ball Pool by Miniclip
When I try to run the app, I get a message saying I need 20mb additional space before I can continue, but that's ridiculous because I'm using a 1TB drive. 
What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

it can be from the emulator and you can search for it on youtube or you can change it to bluestacks / nox or tencent gaming buddy if it has the game or you can use an android os besides your current os such as phoenix os / prime os :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried Phoenix and Bliss OS's and they were very unstable. Android x86 is the most stable for my laptop. I'll check out Prime OS and get back to you.